# Will third party data be migrated

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I migrated my database from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and it was successful. But I noticed that the Magento 1 was using a 3rd party libraries/Module for their transactions. One example is the `Magenest/GiftRegistry` Now I'm wondering will all the data from this module be included in the migration from M1 to M2? What I'm saying is will it also migrate all the orders, reports and URL that was done using this 3rd party library. Will this record be carried over to Magento 2?

Assuming I installed the same library in my Magento 2 application will I be able to see the reports/orders from these module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't migrate the third-party from M1 to M2 because there are differences between M1 and M2.

However, you can possibly do it if you install a new third-party on M2 which has the same functions to the one on M1 or, use your old module if M2 also provides it, then you custom the data and migrate it from M1 to M2.

In fact, this job is quite sensitive and complicated so you can't handle it if you aren't a tech-guru. So you need to find Magento migration experts to help you with the customization and third-party data migration.

Answer (score 0):

I have migrated data generated from additional modules provided the following: the module is installed to Magento 2 and has the same database table structure. The structure can be worked around with `map.xml` to point fields to new locations if need be.